# Multi key keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-code

So, in vscode, there are many shortcuts of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> form. An example is shown below.

[image]

There here is no "+" between <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd>, so I tried the following.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then (release <kbd>K</kbd>, press <kbd>V</kbd>)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then (release <kbd>V</kbd>, press K`)

None of these worked. How do I activate the macro?

Comment: I explained the differences you're referring to here, in case you find it helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74818921/9412456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the bottom left of Visual Studio Code when you press these key combinations. It will help you determine what key combinations are being pressed in the chord:

[image]

To open the markdown previewer to the side:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.
2. Let go of both keys.
3. Press <kbd>V</kbd>.

I suspect you are still holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key when pressing <kbd>V</kbd>, thus Visual Studio Code thinks the chord you are performing is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> which is not a keyboard shortcut by default.

[image]