# I don't understand the format selection (cmd + K cmd + F) shortcut keys in VS Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Can someone please explain to me how the "format selection" (cmd + K cmd + F) shortcut keys - and other shortcuts that seemingly have multiple button press combinations - work in VS Code.

I tried pressing cmd + K and cmd + F simultaneously (though, cmd is listed twice so I am really pressing cmd + K + F in this case) and I have tried hitting them in order. If someone could explain what they mean here, then it would be much appreciated. I am sure it's a simple solution that I have been overlooking for all these years.

Comment: Just hold down `cmd` while you hit `K` and then `F` one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The written format for shortcut expressions use the operators '+' (plus) and ' ' (space) to define whether the expressions on each side of the operator should be pressed simultaneously, or sequentially.

- '+' represents two keys pressed then held simultaneously, in left-to-right order.

  This is the same as typing an uppercase letter using the shift key: `Shift`+`a` -> A
- ' ' represents concatenating the right-hand-side key combo after the left-hand-side combo.

  This is the same as typing an uppercase word using the Shift key: `Shift`+`h` `Shift`+`i` -> HI

In the second example above, note that you can either keep holding `Shift`, or you can release it and press it again for each letter. The same applies with VSCode shortcuts.

In the case of Format Selection (`Cmd`+`k` `Cmd`+`f`), `Cmd` should be held while first `k` *then* `f` are pressed. Pressing `k` and `f` together is a different shortcut entirely (`Cmd`+`k`+`f`), as is pressing `f` and `k` together (`Cmd`+`f`+`k`). Since the left-hand-side key (`Cmd`) is the same for both expressions, you don't need to release it between typing the `k` and `f`.

To get a better grasp of how keyboard shortcuts are expressed, I'd suggest opening the the VSCode Preferences for Keyboard Shortcuts either using the command palette, or using the shortcut: `Cmd`+`k` `Cmd`+`s`: (type `ks` while holding `Cmd`).

Then activate the Record Keys mode (`Alt`+`K`). Now type different key sequences, and it will show you the textual representation in the search bar, along with any shortcuts that match what you typed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It seems so obvious after seeing your answer.